# ORA-00903: invalid table name when selecting from USER

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a task of connecting to a legacy Oracle 9i database and validate users with the new ERP, however when I try to run the query, I get `ORA-00903: invalid table name`

This is the naive query I am starting with: `SELECT * FROM USER`. The table does exist, and I can view it's content using an "in-house database browser" made by some company that no longer exist and to which I do not have the source code for.

Obviously, `SELECT * FROM ALL_USERS` is not what I want, etc.

The point is to validate that some user credentials are valid, the most fundamental concept of authentication, against a table called "USER", with two fields: `USER_NO` and `PASSWORD` (all values stored in plain text (... yeah... I know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user` is a reserved keyword. If you want to use that for a table name you have to quote it (which you already had to do when creating it)

```
select *
from "USER";
```